# Bypass all cacheing on jQuery.autocomplete(1.02)

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, autocomplete, autofill

I am using **jQuery.autocomplete(1.02)** on my search box and I want **exact** string and substring matching. I don't care (yet!) about the database load, I'm happy for it to fire off a query every keystroke and bypass the caching entirely - I just don't want anything missed.

To this end I have tried setting *cacheLength=1*, the minimum permitted, but the autocomplete function refuses to fire off a GET request for each key up.

```
searchbox          GET_request

   'a'       ->    http://localhost/service_search_request?q=a
   'ar'      ->    http://localhost/service_search_request?q=ar
   'ars'     ->    http://localhost/service_search_request?q=ars
```

Instead, it sends the first and the third and misses the second, giving me the wrong results for 'ar' :-/  I've cleared my cache and sessions but it looks like some sort of caching is still going on. AFAIK I have no proxying going on and I'm shift-refreshing each time. It looks likely then that this behavior is from jQuery.autocomplete itself.

**So my questions are...**

**A)** Does this seem likely?  i.e. is it a feature, or maybe a bug?

**B)** If so is there a clean way around it?...

**C)** If not, what autocomplete would you use instead?

Naturally *D) No you're just using it incorrectly you douche!* is always a possibility, and indeed the one I'd prefer having spent time going down this road - assuming it comes with a link to the docs I've failed to find / read!

Cheers,

Roger :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wonder why **cacheLength** doesn't work, but had trouble with autocomplete too. IMHO, there are errors in it. However, in the [list of options](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions), there is a **matchSubset** you could set to false.

**EDIT:**
somewhere around line 335 is a function called "request". You could add some debug messages to it, to see what happens: (note: you need [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) installed or "console" will be unknown)

```
function request(term, success, failure) {

    console.debug("ac request...");

    if (!options.matchCase)
        term = term.toLowerCase();

    var data = cache.load(term);

    console.debug("ac request 1, loaded data from cache: " + data + " term: " + term);

    // recieve the cached data
    if (data && data.length) {
        success(term, data);
    // if an AJAX url has been supplied, try loading the data now
    } else if( (typeof options.url == "string") && (options.url.length > 0) ){

        console.debug("ac request 2, data is not in the cache, request it");
```

"flushCache" can easily be used in the function you can attach / set as options. I used this, to clear the Cache, if there could be more data in the backend:

```
formatItem: function (data,i,n,value){
    if(i === (this.max -1)){
        console.debug("flushCache");
        jQuery(this).flushCache();
    }

    return data[1] + " (" + data[0] + ")";
}
```

Comment: Yeah tried matchSubset set to both true and false - nada :-/
Dunno whether to have a hack at the autocomplete code or to look for another plugin. Not sure my javascript is hot enough to alter/fix it properly though and if I create my own hacky fork I'm lumbered with maintaining it, hmm.

Comment: The docs also mention .flushCache() but I'm not sure how I could get that to trigger just before the autocomplete. If I attach it to a keyUp event that might give race condition no? I guess here must be a way to do it but I can't fathom the syntax & more to the point - I don't know if it would work

Comment: Thanks, sadly I'm still not quite clear on where to hook .flushCache into all this to make it either...

1) preceed every keystroke
or
2) have autocomplete call it every kbd event

I suppose I could attach it to a key down event but I feel sure there must be less sloppy ways I am ignorant of :-/

Comment: Thanks very much for your help BTW, if flushCache turns out to be a dead end I'll go grab the unminified version and try debugging as you suggested.

Comment: I think caching isn't the problem, cause autocomplete avoids this, by apending a timestamp to the request url (like this: "&timestamp=1239808366278"). You can see this wehn using firebug.

Comment: Problem solved - and whaddya know it was my sloppy javascript! Did a debug like you suggested and found out it was using default parameters for Caching and everything else. Turns out I was passing it the parameters incorrectly i.e. not{in:curly, brackets:like:, it:wanted} DOH! Thanx 4 all your help!

Comment: That’s good news! Didn't gave this JavaScript errors or did you just not see them until you installed Firebug?

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem. Caching doesn't work although I have set the option cacheLength to 1.

With your solution to call the flushCache function after each printed term it works. I couldn't use the:

```
if(i === (this.max -1)){
```

since 'i' was e.g 1 after filtering but 'this.max' still 25 as the original backend query resulted in 25 returned rows.

**However**, this bug **ONLY** appears when typing words that contain the swedish characters 'å', 'ä' or 'ö'. So maybe the cashing works as expected but not with these special characters.

Anyway. the solution for me was to always call the flushCache control in the formatItem() function:

```
function formatItem(row, position, n, term) {

    if($("#keywords-h").length > 0){
        $("#keywords-h").flushCache();
        }

        // format Item
        return "<span>" + row[0] + "</span>";
}
```

Hope this helps someone and if someone is having the same problems with special characters please post a reply.

Comment: Update: The problem is partly solved. I made a mistake and hadn't set the matchcontains option to true (which was the backend method we used). This ment that when I continued to add more characters it only kept the terms that started with the input query (using the cache - no new ajax request was made). However, as I had set the cacheLength to 1 I believe it shouldn't have used the cache at all.

Answer (score 1):

Have obviously come to this 18 months on, but

> cacheLength: 0

in the options worked for me. So maybe latest release has fixed the bug?

Comment: I think you're right. cacheLength: 1 did not work for me, but cacheLength: 0 did. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
function requestData(q) {
   if (!options.matchCase) q = q.toLowerCase();

   //-- I turned off this line
   // var data = options.cacheLength ? loadFromCache(q) : null;

   //-- And added this line of code
   var data = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to disable subset matching e.g.

```
$("#query").autocomplete(
    url,
    {
        matchSubset: false
    }
)
```